# Routing and Switching & network monitoring

Tags: network, switching, juniper-junos, troubleshooting, monitoring

hi i am facing problem in juniper switch Model: ex4200-48t ,Junos: 15.1R6.7 . i deploy network monitoring check-MK software. there is showing errors of juniper switch ports and also show in logs file of switch. One of the error is WARN - [DL380-RU-5] (up) MAC: b0:c6:9a:d7:0a:89, 1 Gbit/s (wrong speed, expected: 100 Mbit/s)WARN, in: 0.00 B/s(0.0%), out: 838.52 B/s(0.0%) . i am facing same error in many ports even also in Snmp port. can you explain me how i can troubleshoot and resolve it . also i am attaching output of switch port with the help of command " show interfaces ge-0/0/6 extensive"

[image: 1]
[image: 2][image: 3]

you can check different port errors 
WARN - [DL380-RU-5] (up) MAC: b0:c6:9a:d7:0a:94, 1 Gbit/s (wrong speed, expected: 100 Mbit/s)WARN, in: 0.00 B/s(0.0%), out: 3.94 kB/s(0.0%)
WARN - [DL380-RU-9] (up) MAC: b0:c6:9a:d7:0a:98, 1 Gbit/s (wrong speed, expected: 100 Mbit/s)WARN, in: 0.00 B/s(0.0%), out: 826.83 B/s(0.0%)
WARN - [DL380-RU-9] (up) MAC: b0:c6:9a:d7:0a:97, 1 Gbit/s (wrong speed, expected: 100 Mbit/s)WARN, in: 8.74 B/s(0.0%), out: 912.61 B/s(0.0%)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, paste output as preformatted text instead.

Comment: This is a problem with your Check_MK monitoring software, not your switches.  There are many similar complaints if you Google them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your output, ge-0/0/6.0 is showing `639 carrier transitions` and `4980995 output errors`.

Carrier transitions likely means your link is flapping, and output errors suggest that you are saturating the link.

Use `clear statistics interface ge-0/0/6` and see if the counters both increment again over time - the link flapping is most likely caused by something physical (cabling etc.).